# How to use substr from right hand side to left hand side? How to convert each 8 characters from a string to an int?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i=o;
    string str="12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293";
    while(i<str.length())
     {
       cout<<str.substr(i,8)<<endl;
       i=i+8;
       return 0;
      }
```

*/My output is: 12345678
                    91011121
                    31415161
                    .......
I want to get 8 characters from right to left instead of from left to right. Then, each 8 characters received need to be inserted into an integer variable. Please, can anyone help?*/

Comment: `i=o`, `i+i+8`, return in your while loop. Not sure what you're expecteing...

Comment: It was just a typo. I just need to use substr function. This function has two parameter(first number to start from, number of characters after first parameter). I cannot make the first parameter as the last element of the string. I wanna parse it from right to left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print remaining characters first using mod `%` operator.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str="12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293";
    std::size_t sz = str.size();
    std::size_t i = 0;

    if(sz % 8) {
        cout<<str.substr(i, sz % 8) << ' ' ;
        i += sz % 8;
    }    
    while(i<str.length())
    {
       cout << str.substr(i,8) << ' ';
       i = i+8;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live demo here](http://ideone.com/lEra9F)</kbd>

Now you can use `std::stringstream` or `std::stoi` to convert these strings into number.

```
int strToNum(const string &str)
{
    std::stringstream sstr(str);
    int ret;
    if( sstr >> ret ) {
        return ret;
    } else {
        // Error handling
        throw str + " is not an integer";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand the question...
But if you want the last eight characters you could use:

```
str.substr( str.length() - 8, 8 );
```

To convert a string to an int you can use:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int i = atoi( str.c_str() );
```

Or to convert a character to an int you could use:

```
int i = str[ 0 ] - '0';
```

Comment: I actually to use substr function from the right to left for the whole string (not just 8 characters). I need to parse my string from right to left, 8 characters by 8. Also, for the conversion part, is there a way, in c++, where i can still convert a string to an integer without including other than <iostream> and <string>? I mean I don't wanna use other than these two. Nut still get the same result.

Comment: I'm still not getting the right result. Can anyone help me fix this please?           V="-98884342983742987342987339234098230498203894209928374662342342342356723733661";int k=1;

{
     if(V=='-')
     {
        for(int i=V.length();i>=0;i=i-8)
         {
            string foo1=V.substr(i,8);
            int fo1=atoi(foo1.c_str());

            cout<<"8 charachters # "<<k<<": "<<fo1<<endl;
            k++;
         }

Comment: This is the output I'm looking for: 2373366‌​1;  23423567;  66234234;  09928374;  82038942;    33923409;   87342987;   29837429;  34298374; 00098884

Answer (score 0):

To create a substring from the last 8 digits, use `string::length`:

```
str.substr(str.length() - 8, 8)
```

Then, to convert that substring to int, use [`stoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/):

```
int i = stoi(str.substr(str.length() - 8, 8));
```